# Возможно ли использовать вход mic-in, как audio-out в ноутбуке с Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, железо, pulseaudio

На ноутбуке Asus A72D аудио-выход не подлежит восстановлению. Возможно ли программно настроить микрофонный вход для использования наушников?

lspci определяет аудио-устройство как: Azalia (Intel HDA)

Если возможно, то, что для этого нужно?

(после поверхностного поиска, судя по тому, что удалось найти - аппаратно такая возможность существует)

Comment: нужно искать, как alsa поправить конфиг и оно скорее всего заработает. Но мне кажется, дешевле купить что то вида https://www.thinkpenguin.com/gnu-linux/penguin-usb-20-external-usb-sound-card-gnu-linux

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вот, здесь нашлось решение:
[Using microphone input port as headphone output](https://askubuntu.com/questions/27804/using-microphone-input-port-as-headphone-output)

Оказывается достаточно установить:

```
sudo apt-get install alsa-tools-gui
```

Открыть приложение:

```
hdajackretask
```

Выбрать свою аудио-карту, на `Pink Mic, Rear side` поставить галочку `Override` и выбрать `Headphone`. Нажать кнопку `Install boot override` и перезагрузиться. После этого у меня микрофонный вход заработал как аудио-выход.